# Ruby on Rails Net::HTTP use_ssl throws 'undefined method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my code:

```
sock = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
sock.use_ssl = true
response = sock.start {|http| http.request(req)}
```

here's the error:

```
undefined method `use_ssl=' for #<Net::HTTP www.paypal.com:443 open=false>
```

google is getting me nothing!

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because the function is `sock.use_ssl?` and it returns a boolean, it is not a setter method.

It also appears to always return false. It is overridden in the `Net::HTTPS` package, which is probably what you should be using if you want to do any SSL stuff.

[Here is the ruby doc](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M000669)

Comment: do you have any further information on this Net::HTTPS package.  the only info i can find suggests the code that i have is in fact correct for setting Net::HTTP to use HTTPS...e.g. http://perfectionlabstips.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/how-to-open-a-https-session-in-ruby/

Comment: @Chris - I don't have any more info really. If you look at the ruby-library docs they show that the blog you are reading is incorrect.

Comment: what is ssl anyway? How does a server require it?

Answer (score 19):

Require 'net/https' in addition to 'net/http'. Then `use_ssl=` will be defined.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
connection = Net::HTTP::new 'www.example.com'
connection.use_ssl = true
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.   I get: `require': no such file to load -- net/https (LoadError)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the following snippet:

```
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  http.request(req)
end
```

You need to do the set for the use_ssl on the http object not on the request object. I struggled with this and found my answer here: https://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post/issues/18

Answer (score 1):

If you get " `require': no such file to load -- net/https (LoadError)", then that's because you don't have it installed.

If you haven't already got it, you might need ssl libraries on your server. For example, on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
aptitude --assume-yes install libssl-dev
```

If you're unlucky, you might need to rebuild Ruby, with SSL support. If building manually, add `--with-openssl` to the configure options.

Then you need the gem:

```
gem install  openssl-nonblock --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

And now, at least in my experience, it should work...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do a https get request:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://secure.com/")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
```

source: http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html